# apc.filter in APC

Tags: filter, apc

I'm trying to use such function as apc.filter in APC.But all, that i have done, didnt work

There are 2 task that I should done.

1)Need to include 1 catalog for caching.My code in apc.ini

```
apc.cache by default Off
apc.filter = "+/path1/.*"
```

Such option doesnt work.It's still caching

2)Need to exlude 3 catalogs on the server that shouldnt be cached,for example my code in apc.ini for such task

```
apc.cache by default On 

apc.filter = "-/path1/path2/.*,
apc.filter = "-/path3/path4/.*,
apc.filter = "-/path5/path6/.*"
```

Can somebody help me with it?plz

Answer (score 5):

apc.filter does not work for absolute path
http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters

You can try to enable/disable apc for particular folder by using .htaccess directives.

In my case I need to disable APC cache for whole site, so I put the following into root .htaccess:

php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off

And it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made a typo: it's apc.filters not apc.filter

For an example of what you're trying to achieve:

```
apc.filters = /path1/path2/.*,/path3/path4/.*,/path5/path6/.*
```

should do the trick, with a default cache set to On.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing for my development environment. Since both production and development code were there on the same server, I wanted a way not to cache "test" directory.
I tried using

```
apc.filters -/my loc/my_test/.*,-/full_path/my_test/.*
```

But this does not work. The simplest fix is to modify .htaccess in your directory that you want to block being cached

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off</IfModule>
```

And it works beautifully.:)